# Draw Lines between pins with iphones Map Kit

Tags: iphone, sdk, mapkit, draw

Is it possible to draw custom lines between two or more locations with the MapKit? Or do I need a custom overlay? Is there some kind of tutorial about this topic?

I have a working "Google Maps Application" and now I want to connect my locations with straight lines.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false

Answer (score 2):

You can draw lines in map using MKPolyline.

See this link

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136

Comment: Do you have a sample where the MKPolyline is clickable and fire an event..?

Comment: @meersmans: nice question :) +1.


You can subclass `MKPolylineView`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Draw Lines Between Two pins

See The Link:
[mapkit route](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)